# Git: new branch not getting pushed

Tags: git

I created a branch, say "dev" which was based off say branch "Base" and then merged it with Upstream content (I want to keep Base clean till I am done with my testing). After resolving conflicts, I ran the command git commit -a -m "comment" and it went through. Next, I ran git push, hoping the new branch would be created on the git server and also my merged content on dev will be seen. But, when I ran git push, the command gave output "Everything up-to-date" and I do not see the new branch on the git server. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: need more info like what version of git you are using, is dev setup as a tracking branch?  can you paste your .git/config file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

See if you have created the branch on the remote repo:

```
$ git branch -av
```

You probably haven't. You can create the branch by explicitly stating you want to push it:

```
$ git push origin dev
```

By default git pushes all branches that have a respective branch on the remote (new branches don't).

Comment: `git push -u origin dev` will also create the local tracking information so that you can use just `git push` later

Comment: @abresas, That was absolutely perfect. I ran the git push origin dev after I saw the branch wasn't on the remote and it worked. Thank you.